# The Duke - Assassin Movement

Tags: the-duke

We have been playing the game, The Duke, and confusion came up regarding the movement for the Assassin tile.

[image: Assassin Tile]

Based on the slide rules, a tile can move as many spaces as they want in the shown direction until they would hit another tile, friendly or enemy.

The jump rules state that a tile can jump over an adjacent tile to the space beyond it.

So the question is, for this tile with a jump slide, can the slide begin in the adjacent tile or must the assassin move at least two spaces away?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official rules](http://www.catalystgamelabs.com/download/The%20Duke%20Rulebook%20Lo-Res_FINAL.pdf), the Slide and Jump Slide icons allow

> ...a Troop Tile to move *any number of squares* in the direction shown

It seems that the icons are place on the outside edges as emphasis that their movement is not limited in that direction.

[image: Screen shot of description of Jump and Slide icons]

Comment: While I understand your logic, this seems unnecessary since slides are used on plenty of other tiles. I see no reason they would put the jump slide farther away from the icon just to make sure I remember how a slide works.

Answer (score 1):

According to: https://boardgamegeek.com/article/13008817#13008817
The Assassin tile (the only tile in the original game using a Jump Slide icon) can not move to the adjacent square. The game rules (excerpts quoted below) are very clear on this, and their ruling from GENCON is incorrect and not supported by those official rules. The misconception seems to be centered around the name. People seem to believe a “Jump Slide” should, first jump, then slide; even if the rules say otherwise.

I believe Catalyst should either change the rules, or follow them an advise GENCON on the rules.

SLIDE
This icon allows a Troop Tile to move |any| number of squares in the direction shown...

JUMP SLIDE
This icon follows the |exact| rules for Slide, with the following |addition|: this icon |allows| a Troop Tile to move in the direction of the Jump Slide icon and completely ignore |any| tile that might be adjacent, along the direction indicated.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are still curious about Assassin, but even if not, maybe someone other is.

So, briefly:

- Assassin *has to* make a jump, and then slide. This makes impossible for him to move into adjacent square.
- You cannot make a slide when capturing tile after jump.
- Slide action is optional - you can stay in place after non-capturing jump.

Src: https://boardgamegeek.com/article/13008817#13008817

Comment: The existing answer cites and provides the rules for a Jump Slide, which imply that the jump is **not** required. The Jump Slide is in all ways exactly the same as a Slide, except that the Troop Tile may ignore an adjacent tile before continuing to move.

Comment: So placement of icons on the Assassin is quite misleading (one empty space between a pawn in the middle and jump-slide icon suggests requirement of jumping).

Comment: Also, take a look at this clarification:
https://boardgamegeek.com/article/13008817#13008817